# Find the largest minimum distance of n points in a convex compact set

Tags: general-topology, optimization, convex-optimization, operations-research

Suppose you have to place n points in a convex compact set X $\in R^m$, using the Euclidean distance as the metric, how does the largest minimum distance between those n points change with the number of points n?

To clarify, when you place n points in the set X, you can compute the minimum distance between those n points. I would like to have the placement such that this minimum distance is maximized. I assume that this largest minimum distance decreases with the number of points n. My question is at what rate this distance decreases?

Comment: "largest" does not seem to be compatible with "random".  I would also suggest specifying your space: it will make a difference whether you are considering a line segment or a disk or a ball.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for pointing this out. I deleted the word "random". I was referring to any set in $R^m$.

Comment: I found this refers to the max-min separation problems, I would be greatly helped if you can come up with the exact, or upper bound of this decrease rate, for sphere, cubes, or whatever convex compact subset in $R^m$.

Answer (score 3):

It would be difficult  for a given $X$ and a given $k$ to find

$$\rho_{X,k}\colon =\max_{a_1, \ldots, a_k \in X} \min_{i\ne j} d(a_i, a_j)$$

except some easy particular cases ($X$ is a segment, or a circle).

I think that $\rho_{X, k}$ behaves like the radius of $k$ balls tightly packed inside $X$, so it should be

$$k \cdot \rho_{X,k}^n\simeq \operatorname{vol}(X)$$

Comment: Thank you for giving the exact formulation, which can further be formulated as a non-convex optimization problem. I agree with you it might be a very difficult problem. The last point is also interesting.

Comment: @Sen Zhan: A related problem is: find the largest radius of $k$ disks that can be packed into a domain.

Comment: I also came across this paper, describing it as the optimal separation problem. Some computational results are given, but not a rate. http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:558519/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since every nonempty compact convex subset of $R^m$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball of suitable dimension, your argument can be extended to the mth-dimensional inscribed regular polytope that connects the n points that you want to place in the convex set.